# How to add zeros between hex numbers with sed/awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file contains that strings

```
    abc = <0x12345678>;
    abc = <0x01234 0x56789>;
    abc = <0x123 0x456 0x789>;
    abc = <0x0 0x01234 0x0 0x56789>;
    abc = <0x012 0x345>, <0x678 0x901>;
    def = <0x12345 0x67890>;
```

I need to convert it to file contains

```
    abc = <0 0x12345678>;
    abc = <0 0x01234 0 0x56789>;
    abc = <0x123 0x456 0x789>;
    abc = <0x0 0x01234 0x0 0x56789>;
    abc = <0 0x012 0 0x345>, <0 0x678 0 0x901>;
    def = <0x12345 0x67890>;
```

So I need to add zeros before HEX numbers if strings starts with *'abc = '*, that are no more than 2 HEX numbers between couple of triangular brackets and there isn't *0x0* between that HEX numbers. How I can do it with *sed*, *awk* or another bash tools?

Comment: Could the file contain the line like `abc = <0x012 0x345>, <0x678 0x901 0x010>;` ? (groups with different number of hexs)

Comment: groups only with same number of hexs

Comment: the condition *there isn't 0x0 between that HEX numbers* is already **covered** by previous rule *no more than **2** HEX numbers between couple of triangular brackets*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Leading white spaces [are intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578286/how-to-add-something-between-patterns-with-sed-awk/58578498#comment103472147_58578498).

Comment: Is the line `abc = <0x0 0x1234>` possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible and don't require changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/abc = </{/<[^ >]* [^ >]* /!s/0x/0 &/g}'
```

Explanation:

```
/abc = </{/<[^ >]* [^ >]* /!s/0x/0 &/g}
/abc = </                                Operate on lines containing "abc = <"
         {                            }  Group the commands together
                           !             Negate the condition
          /<[^ >]* [^ >]* /              Match if lines contain more than two elements after <
                            s/0x/0 &/    Prepend "0 " to "0x"
                                     g   Globally, i.e. replace as many times as possible
```

Comment: Nearly worked. `sed '/abc = </{/<[^ >]* [^ >]* /!s/0x/0 &/g}; s/abc = <0 0x0 0/abc = <0x0/g; s/abc = <0 0x0>/abc = <0x0>/g'` helped me. Thanks!