# How to split triange brackets to couple of them?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have file contains this

```
abc = <0x0 0x1>;
abc = <0x0 0x1 0x2>;
def = <0x0123 0x4567 0x89AB 0xCDEF>;
def = <0x0 0x1>;
def = <0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4>;
abc = <0x0 0x2 0x4 0x6>;
def = <0x0 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5>;
```

I need to convert it to

```
abc = <0x0 0x1>;
abc = <0x0 0x1 0x2>;
def = <0x0123 0x4567>, <0x89AB 0xCDEF>;
def = <0x0 0x1>;
def = <0x1 0x2>, <0x3 0x4>;
abc = <0x0 0x2 0x4 0x6>;
def = <0x0 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5>;
```

I need to split only triangle brackets with 4 HEX-numbers between them to couple of brackets, separated with comma, with 2 HEX-numbers inside, and only on lines which beginning with 'def = ' (or 'def = ' with any symbols before its). How I can do this with sed, awk or grep?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: beacuse it isn't beginnig with 'def = '

Comment: @ComptrollerChanel, Sure, please add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I don't even know roughly how to implement it

Comment: @ComptrollerChanel, I understand and we all are here to learn from each other, on SO we encourage users to put some efforts in their question and when they stuck somewhere they will get guidance, you could use search functionality of this site too before posting.

Comment: I recommend that you take a closer look at the answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58579677/3776858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/def/ && match($0,/<.*>/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  num=split(val,array," ")
  if(num==4){
    val=array[1] OFS array[2]">, <" array[3] OFS array[4]
  }
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1
' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp && mv temp Input_file` in above code.

Comment: Does not work. The output is the same as the input. Maybe it doesn't take into account lines with spaces or tabs before ' def = '

Comment: @ComptrollerChanel, yes I didn't consider spaces present before, could you please check now?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^ *def =/s/(<\S+ \S+) (\S+ \S+>;)$/\1>, <\2/' file
```

If a line begins with `def =` and contains 4 fields between `<` and `>` insert `>, <` between the 2nd and 3rd of these fields.